# Comparing within-subject variability across two groups

Tags: variance, psychology, variability

How can I compare the variability in a dependent variable for individuals across groups?

I don't really have the statistics vocabulary to ask this question, so I'll paint a picture instead. Let's say I have two groups individuals: group A and group B. Group A took a medication (or has some gene) that unpredictably alters reaction time: sometimes the people in Group A respond more slowly, but other times they respond really fast. Individuals in Group B tend to vary less in reaction times. The mean reaction times for individuals in Group A and Group B are about the same: only the variances differ.

If I have multiple measurements of reaction time for each individual, how would I show that individuals in group A react more variability compared to those in group B? What statistical tests or tools would I use?

Comment: How many reaction time observations do you have per individual? Do you have any idea of how the reaction times are distributed? Are they quite quick reaction times (i.e. right skewed) or longer?

Comment: I have >1000 observations for 20 individuals. Distributed normally (very slight left skew because there is no ceiling).

Comment: Ok - do you care about modeling and predicting the response times or do you just want a simple test between the variances in each group? Also, do you want to use Bayesian or Frequentist methods? There's a number of possible ways to approach this problem, so it would be good to narrow any answer down.

Comment: @awhug Thanks a bunch for your help! My primary concern is a test for variances between groups--i.e., to show that Group A has higher variance than Group B. A frequentist methods is great for now, but if you don't mind quickly mentioning the Bayesian method for me research later, that would be wonderful!